# Cant install my own extension "Download Interrupted"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Tried all ways - reupload, resize, write blank extension, wait 12 hours, use another google-account, broswer, os, another archiver, etc.
I create extension, upload it to dashboard, publish it. When i try to install it from store i get this error:

[image]

Even sample extension from google developer "get started" manual fails with this "Download Interrupted" error. I've seen a lot of same question on google groups, but no answers. Any one find out why this happens?